# .net soap client to java soap service, fully qualified namespace

Tags: java, .net, wcf, c#-4.0, soap

Recently, I got an integration work try to make WCF to work with legacy Java soap service. After generate the proxy by wsdl command, we found the soap message WCF generated was not validate for that service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-e497560b-df45-457d-b60d-1dd68430eec8">
            <wsse:Username xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">.....</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">.....</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
        <OrganizationToken xmlns="http://www.strongmail.com/services/2009/03/02/schema">
            <organizationName xmlns="">.....</organizationName>
        </OrganizationToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <list xmlns="http://www.strongmail.com/services/2009/03/02/schema">
        <filter xsi:type="SystemAddressFilter">
            <isAscending>true</isAscending>
            <pageNumber>0</pageNumber>
            <recordsPerPage>10</recordsPerPage>
            <typeCondition>
                <value>FROM</value>
                <operator>EQUAL</operator>
            </typeCondition>
        </filter>
    </list>
</soap:Body>
```

but the java service expect that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-e497560b-df45-457d-b60d-1dd68430eec8">
            <wsse:Username xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">.....</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">.....</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
        <OrganizationToken xmlns="http://www.strongmail.com/services/2009/03/02/schema">
            <organizationName xmlns="">.....</organizationName>
        </OrganizationToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <list xmlns="http://www.strongmail.com/services/2009/03/02/schema">
        **<filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="SystemAddressFilter">**
            <isAscending>true</isAscending>
            <pageNumber>0</pageNumber>
            <recordsPerPage>10</recordsPerPage>
            <typeCondition>
                <value>FROM</value>
                <operator>EQUAL</operator>
            </typeCondition>
        </filter>
    </list>
</soap:Body>
```

anyone know is there just a attribute or setting can do the change?

Comment: Be sure to generate SOAP11 instead of SOAP12.

Comment: Yes, I use 'Svc.SoapVersion = SoapProtocolVersion.Soap11;' to force soap11

Comment: @Blam I already setup as soap 1.1, but serialization of soap message doesn't change. Anyway, finally, I do manually hack, to inject namespace before request sends